# Asp.Net MVC and WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I have MVC and WebForms in the same Site/virtual directory?

I have a website running WebForms but I would like to implement MVC. Note: the website also have some Classic ASP files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix all in the same project.

See [Plug-In Hybrids](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) that shows how to mix all of technologies.

You can add MVC to existing WinForms application without problems. You may need to add `IgnoreRoute` rules for your existing pages. Classic ASP may need special handling (just potential  - no idea about it really).

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{myWebForms}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```